# Strange char* compile error?

Tags: c++, reference, char

Anything wrong with my code below? I got the compile error!

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

void foo(char* & p)
{
 return;
}

int main()
{
  BYTE * buffer;
  // error C2664: 'foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'char *&'
  foo ((char*)buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
George

Comment: I think ChrisW actually fixed the bug in your code while editing... you were casting a BYTE * to a (char) instead of a (char*).

Comment: Not so, you cannot pass a temporary by non-const reference, so the error is still there: the cast creates a temporary and that cannot be passed by reference.

Comment: @UncleZeiv the edit history says I did, but I don't remember doing that. I can't explain it. Could it have been someone else, the OP even, doing a concurrent edit?

Comment: @ChrisW - the '*' was in the original post, but it wasn't displayed because it wasn't in a code-formatted block, so Markup treated it as a formatting command/tag/whatever.  So your edit didn't add it, but did make it show up...

Answer (score 14):

When you cast the `BYTE*` to `char*` a unnamed temporary entity is created with the type `char*`. The function you call takes a reference to a `char*` but you can't take a reference to such a temporary entity because it is not a real variable.

Comment: I'm not sure about that... it's a pointer, you are just telling the compiler to trust you... I'm pretty sure there's no temporary involved here.

Comment: fixing it depends on what you want to do and the reason why that function takes a reference to a pointer. @UncleZeiv - There is no spoon.

Comment: "not a real value" - I think you mean not an l-value. Correct answer though. +1

Comment: I have voted this up for its correctness and codelogic's for its solution. Merging both would make a correct and complete answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can perform a `reinterpret_cast<char*&>` instead of a static cast

```
foo (reinterpret_cast<char*&>(buffer));
```

Or, you can make the argument a const reference:

```
void foo(char* const & p)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The parameter of foo is a reference-to-a-pointer. buffer is a BYTE pointer. Reference require an exact match, assignment-compatible won't do.

Two solutions:

1) you probably don't need the '&' in front of p. Loose it and the code will compile.

2) Use a correctly typed variable so the reference will work:

```
 BYTE * buffer;
 char * b = (char *) buffer;
 foo (b);
 buffer = (BYTE*) b;  // because foo may change b
```

Comment: Assuming that a side-effect of foo is to modify the passed-in parameter, you'd better also do "buffer = (BYTE*)b;" after calling foo.

Comment: @ChrisW: you are right, I Will edit it in. Makes the ref issue cleare too.

Answer (score 2):

The `buffer` pointer is an "lvalue", but when the cast operation is applied to it, the expression:

```
(char*) buffer
```

is an "rvalue" (actually a "modifiable rvalue" - but I think that only matters in the upcoming C++0x).  Non-const references cannot be bound to rvalues.

However, *const* references can be bound to rvalues. So the following modification to your program will compile:

```
void foo(char* const& p)  // added 'const'
```

Stephan T. Lavavej recently posted a blog entry that has great information about lvalues, rvalues, and references:

- [Rvalue References: C++0x Features in VC10, Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx)

The article is actually about the new "rvalue references" that are coming in C++0x, but it has a great explanation of what lvalues and rvalues are and how they can and cannot work with references in C++98.  It's a long read, but very much well worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a variable reference, but there is no such variable of type char* you could refer to.

It should work this way if I remember correctly:

```
BYTE * buffer;
char* ptr = (char*)buffer;
foo(ptr); // now you have a matching variable to refer to.
```

Maybe it would be easier to just pass a value instead of a reference.

Comment: Because you want to pass a reference. And you cannot reference to a variable that does not exist. So you need to create one. 

But I think that reference passing is not needed here. Why not just pass a value? void foo(char* p)

Comment: It might not work as expected: if the function changes the received pointer, changes will be made to the ptr var and not to the original buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when you say

```
(char)buffer
```

You are lying to the compiler - buffer is pointer, not a char.

Secondly, even if the cast worked, it would produce a temporary, which cannot be bound to a non-const reference.

So, yes, there are at least two things wrong with your code.

Comment: That's not what he said, he is casting to a char*.

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this:

```
int main() { 
  BYTE * buffer; 
  char* pbuf = (char*)buffer;
  foo(pbuf);
}
```

Comment: If f() changes the received pointer, the change will apply to pbuf and not buffer.